# Measuring the degree of convergence of a stochastic process

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods

Consider a set of random variables $(X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_k)$ that are i.i.d. $Bernoulli(p)$

While I do not know $p$, I can estimate it using
$$
Y(k)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i
$$

Notice that $Y(k)$ is a random variable, and its distribution has mean $p$ and variance $\frac{p(1-p)}{k}$. So $Y(k)$ is a consistent estimator of $p$.

**Question:**
How can I determine the sample size that guarantees a minimum (arbitrary) 'degree of convergence' of the estimator? In other words, what is the point after which we can be confident that increasing the sample size from $k$ to $k+1$ will only yield a small change in our estimate of $p$ (for any $p$)?

One idea I had was to look at the convergence of the variance of the sequence of estimators that is obtained by increasing $k$ gradually; that is 
$$S(k)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k (Y(i)-\bar{Y}(i))^2$$
for $\bar{Y(k)}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k Y(i)$

Numerically, I find that $S(k)$ converges to $0$ as expected; so perhaps what I need is a condition on $S(k)$?

Comment: How do you "know that $S(k)$ tends to zero as $k$ tends to infinity"?

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks – seems the problem was not well posed in the first instance. I've edited it

Comment: It depends on your measure of smallness. If $p $ is close to 0, say, then a small error in absolute terms is a larger error in relative terms.

Comment: Does this help?... The simplest standard [confidence interval for a binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), with a given confidence level $1-\alpha$, has half-width $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}Y(k) \left(1-Y(k)\right)}<z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}}=z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{k}}.$ So for any desired width $w>0$ (no matter how small), the interval $Y(k)\pm\frac{w}{2}$ has *at least* a $1-\alpha$ level of confidence if $k\ge\left(\frac{1}{w}z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)^2$.

Comment: @r.e.s. made a useful observation, which can actually be improved a little bit. Instead of looking at absolute widths, we can look at relative widths. To that end it is better to look at $\min \{ p,1-p \}$ rather than $p$ itself; let's call that minimum $r$. With that in mind, the situation in terms of relative errors is actually rather bad. That's because your point estimator for $\min \{ p,1-p \}$ is $\min \{ Y(k),1-Y(k) \}$. Let's call that $P$.

Comment: (Cont.) Then the length of the confidence interval is roughly proportional to $\sqrt{P}$, more precisely it is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} z_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt{P} \sqrt{1-P}$. This is bad: when the true value of $r$ is small, $P$ is usually small, and if $P$ is small then the length of the confidence interval obtained is quite large relative to its center. Also, as the true value of $r$ goes down the validity of the normal approximation is degraded, but that's not so bad until $r$ is unusually small. (If this issue interests you, the Berry-Esseen theorem may interest you.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Let me call the value of $k$ answering my question as the "optimal sample size".  If I understand correctly, your proposed line of reasoning gives an optimal $k$ that makes no use of the actual successive estimates (it is in fact unique for any $w$ and $\alpha$). Since convergence depends on what the underlying true probability is ($p$ in my question), it seems that I am wasting important information by not considering what the interim estimates of $p$ are (i.e. the transition of the estimator towards convergence)...

Comment: @EOO You may have missed an important step in what r.e.s. did. The length of the confidence interval can be calculated as soon as we know $Y(k)$. It can be uniformly bounded independent of $Y(k)$ because $p(1-p) \leq 1/4$ for any $p \in [0,1]$. Thus, if you want a given *absolute* error at a given level of confidence, you can ensure that with a fixed value of $k$. For example, you could take $\alpha=0.05$ so that $z_{1-\alpha/2}=1.96$ and $w=10^{-2}$. Then your confidence interval with $\alpha=0.05$ will always have length less than $w$ provided that $k$ is larger than $196^2 \approx 38000$.

Comment: @Ian Yes – this bound comes from assuming the highest possible true variance of the estimator (i.e. $p=0.5$). My point is that it seems rather strong to assume the worst-case scenario to solve for  $k$ ex-ante, rather than using information from the interim estimates that I obtain from sequentially increasing sample size...

Comment: @EOO Unfortunately because of stochasticity there is no real guarantee that you won't have a huge line of $1$s (or $0$s) anytime soon. Still, I pointed out something that you can do a bit better rather than simply jumping straight to the worst case. (That said, in many real cases, it is actually faster to jump straight to the worst case rather than doing some logical checking to determine whether to stop at every step.)

Comment: @r.e.s. I have been doing a bit of thinking about this, and it seems that focusing on the confidence interval for a binomial proportion is indeed a good way of going about it. If you post your comment above as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest standard [confidence interval for a binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), with a given confidence level $1-\alpha$, has half-width $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}Y(k) \left(1-Y(k)\right)}<z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}}=z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{k}}.$ So for any desired width $w>0$ (no matter how small), the interval $Y(k)\pm\frac{w}{2}$ has *at least* a $1-\alpha$ level of confidence if $k\ge\left(\frac{1}{w}z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)^2$.

Comment: I have continued working on this, and I have formulated a new, but related problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912242/stopping-rule-for-quality-control-problem – you might want to have a look (and thanks in advance for any help!)