# Stopping rule for quality control problem

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, bayesian

**Problem:**

Suppose I have a production process that yields output in batches of $n$ items. For each batch, I can test whether they are of good or bad quality. Let $q_i\in\{1,0\}$  be the quality of tested item $i$.

If more than half of the items are ‘bad’, the batch should be discarded. In other words: the batch should be discarded if the average quality of items is $\bar{q}(n)<0.5$.

Suppose testing is sequential (i.e. you learn the quality of items one at the time), and each test is a random draw from a Bernoulli distribution with unknown mean $p$.

*I would like to know when to stop testing items in a batch, in order to decide whether to discard it without testing all items,  and yet be statistically confident that the outcome (discard vs not discard) is the same as the one that would have been reached if all items had been tested.*

**What I currently have:**

If I knew $p$, I could use a [normal approximation to estimate the confidence interval of the binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) $\bar{q}(k)$ for any $k$. With this, for any arbitrary width of the interval, I could calculate the number of tests that are required to achieve a given confidence level (let me call such number of tests $k^*$).

Since I don’t know $p$, one option would be to solve for $k^*$ assuming the worst case scenario (i.e. $p=0.5$). This was proposed (and discussed) in a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820457/measuring-the-degree-of-convergence-of-a-stochastic-process?noredirect=1#comment3729286_1820457).

This approach, however, does not take into account that $n$ is finite, so once many items have been tested, it becomes very unlikely that one more test will swing the outcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bayesian Approach**

Samples $(q_i)_{i=1..k}$ are taken sequentially (without replacement) from a batch of size $n$ for the purpose of making inferences about $\bar{q}(n)$, the unknown proportion of "good" items in that batch. Two criteria are assumed:

1. A real number $acc\in(0,1)$ (e.g. $acc=0.5$) that serves to define the "acceptability" of a batch; specifically, the batch is considered *un*acceptable iff $\bar{q}(n) < acc$.
2. A real number $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ (e.g. $\epsilon=0.05$) that serves as an "effective convergence" criterion; specifically, if a sequence of probabilities $p_k$ is known to converge to either $0$ or $1$, it will be considered to have "effectively converged" to $0$ (resp. $1$) if $\ p_k \le \epsilon$ (resp. $\ p_k \ge 1-\epsilon$).

Sampling will therefore stop when $p_k$, the posterior probability of $\{\bar{q}(n)<acc\}$ given $(q_i)_{i=1..k}$, has "effectively converged" to $0$ or $1$ (as it must do for some $k\in 1..n$, because necessarily $p_n\in\{0,1\}$). Thus, the sequential procedure is as follows:

1. $k \leftarrow 0$.
2. $k \leftarrow k+1$; sample $q_k$, yielding $(q_i)_{i=1..k}$.
3. Compute the posterior distribution of the unknown $\bar{q}(n)$, given $(q_i)_{i=1..k}$.
4. Compute the posterior probability $p_k = P\big(\bar{q}(n)< acc\mid (q_i)_{i=1..k}\big)$.
5. If $p_k \le \epsilon$, decide $\{\bar{q}(n)\ge acc\}$; else if $p_k \ge 1-\epsilon$, decide $\{\bar{q}(n)< acc\}$; else goto (2).

**Posterior distribution**

Let $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k q_i = k\,\bar{q}(k)$ for $k\in 0..n$. Now

$$\begin{align}
&P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s\} \\
&= \int_0^1 P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s, p\!=\!p'\}\,f_{p\mid S_k}(p'\mid s)\,dp'\tag{A1}\\
&= \int_0^1 P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s, p\!=\!p'\}\,\frac{P\{S_k\!=\!s\mid p\!=\!p'\}f(p')}{\int_0^1 P\{S_k\!=\!s\mid p\!=\!p''\}f(p'')dp''}\,dp'\tag{A2}\\
\end{align}
$$

where

$$\begin{align}
&P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s, p\!=\!p'\}= \binom{n-k}{t-s}(p')^{t-s}(1-p')^{n-k-(t-s)}I_{\{s,...,s+n-k\}}(t)\tag{B1}\\
&P\{S_k\!=\!s\mid p\!=\!p'\}= \binom{k}{s}(p')^s(1-p')^{k-s}I_{\{0,...,k\}}(s)\tag{B2}\\
\end{align}
$$
and $f()$ is the prior density for $p$. For the sake of modeling various potential prior states of knowledge about $p$, we use a Beta distribution with positive real parameters $\alpha, \beta$ (with $\alpha=\beta=1$ producing a uniform distribution):
$$f(p') = \frac{1}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)}(p')^{\alpha-1}(1-p')^{\beta-1}I_{(0,1)}(p')\tag{B3}
$$
where 
$$\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)= \int_0^1(p')^{\alpha-1}(1-p')^{\beta-1}\,\mathrm{d}p'=\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} .
$$
Note that (B1) describes the fact that, conditional on $S_k\!=\!s,\ p\!=\!p'$, 
$$S_n\,=\,S_k + \sum_{i=k+1}^n q_i\ \sim\ s + \text{Binomial}(n-k,p').$$
and that (B2) describes the fact that, conditional on $p\!=\!p'$,
$$S_k\,\sim\,\text{Binomial}(k,p').$$

Substituting (B) into (A) and performing the integrations gives the posterior distribution in terms of a binomial coefficient and standard Beta functions, for any $s\in 0..k$ and $k\in 0..n$:

> $$\begin{align}
> &P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s\} = \binom{n-k}{t-s}\ \frac{\mathrm{B}(\alpha+t,\ \beta+n-t)}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha+s,\ \beta+k-s)}\ I_{\{s,...,s+n-k\}}(t).\tag{C1}\\
> \end{align}
> $$

Finally,

> $$\begin{align}
> p_k &= P\big(\bar{q}(n)<acc\mid (q_i)_{i=1..k}\big)\\
> &= \sum_{t\ <\ acc\cdot n}P\{S_n\!=\!t\mid S_k\!=\!s\}.\tag{C2}
> \end{align}
> $$

**NB**: When $k=0$, we have $P(S_n=t\mid S_0=0)$ and $p_0$, which are the *prior* (before-sampling) probabilities of $\{S_n=t\}$ and $\{\bar{q}(n)<acc\}$, respectively, deriving entirely from the $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ prior assigned to the Bernoulli process parameter $p$. (Extremely "informative" priors may result in $p_0$ effectively equal to $0$ or $1$, hence accepting or rejecting the batch even before any sampling is done.)

**Implementation in [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/)**

```
# pr(S_n = t | S_k = s)
def P(t,n,k,s,a,b): return binomial(n-k,t-s) * beta(a+t,b+n-t) / beta(a+s,b+k-s)

# pr(S_n < acc*n | S_k = s)
def Pun(acc,n,k,s,a,b): 
    tot = 0; accn = acc*n
    for t in [s..s+n-k]:
        if t < accn: tot += P(t,n,k,s,a,b)
    return tot    

# example 
n = 20; acc = 0.5
a = 1; b = 1

# display the posterior probabilities pr(S_n < acc*n | S_k = s)
for k in [0..n]:
    print "k=%3d:   " % k,
    for s in [0..k]:
        print "%.2f" % Pun(acc,n,k,s,a,b),
    print
```

**Example**

Here's a picture of the decisions that would be made in the case of a non-informative (uniform) prior for $p$, batch size $n=20$, criteria $acc=0.5,\ \epsilon=0.05$ (computations programmed in Sage):

[image]

**Laplace's "Rule of Succession"**

Note that the present [Beta-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) model exhibits [Laplace's "Rule of Succession"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) as a special case of equation (C1) (changing $n\to n+1,\ k\to n$):
$$P(S_{n+1}=s+1 \mid S_n=s) = \frac{s+\alpha}{n+\alpha+\beta}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this – very clear and flexible implementation of the Bayesian approach! I don't use Sage – but I suppose the code is intuitive anyway. I use Mathematica, so I should be able to translate it... Would you mind sharing the numerical example ?

Comment: @EOO - I've expressed the posterior in terms of a binomial coefficient and ratio of standard Beta functions, which simplifies the code and is likely to be available in mathematical software (e.g., SageMath, Mathematica, etc.).

Comment: @ r.e.s. - your code was very helpful. I've been implementing some simulations and I am quite surprised by the performance of the algorithm! Generating 1000 random batches of 100 items (with $p=0.6$), in 80% of the batches the algorithm makes a decision with tests from half or less of the items – and gets it right  98% of the times! And that's even after feeding it an uninformative prior for the distribution of $p$ (i.e. replacing $\alpha=\beta=1$ in your expressions)...  Do those figures even sound in the right ballpark for such algorithm?

Comment: ...I forgot to say, the numbers I mention above are from implementing the algorithm with $\epsilon=0.05$ and $acc=0.5$.

Comment: @EOO - Simulating $10^4$ batches of size $10^2$ with $p=0.6,\  \alpha=\beta=1,\ \epsilon=0.05$ and $acc=0.50$, I found $94\%$ of all batches were decided correctly; $84\%$ of all batches were decided by testing half or less of the items, $93\%$ of these decisions being correct. When $p=0.5$ (the worst case, keeping all other parameters the same), then $83\%$ of all batches were decided correctly; $63\%$ of all batches were decided by testing half or less of the items, $75\%$ of these decisions being correct.

Comment: Wow, OK, so it seems my implementation is correct. Great! Thanks for checking

Comment: I am interested in a slightly more general version of this problem, in which quality tests may have different weights. I posted a new question here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020212/dynamic-voting-quorum). It would be great to have your inputs @r.e.s.!!

Comment: You may be interested to know I have set a bounty on a related question that builds on this answer. Any input is much appreciated