# Numerical voting algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

### This question relates closely to other posts. See note at the bottom.

**Problem:**

Suppose that a committee with $n$ members needs to vote on whether to accept a proposition.

Each member in the committee can cast a yes/no vote ($q_i\in\{1,0\}$ for $i\in \{1,2,...,n \}$), and each member's vote has a  different weight ($w_i\in[0,1]$ for $i\in \{1,2,...,n \}$).

The committee rules stipulate that the proposition is to be accepted if the weighted average of votes is more than 50%, namely, if $$\bar{q}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i q_i>0.5$$

Suppose that (i) voting is sequential, (ii) each vote is a random draw from a Bernoulli distribution with unknown mean $p$, and (iii) the order of voting is independent of voting weights.

*I would like to establish a **numerical algorithm**, such that a decision (accept vs reject) is made with only the first $k$ votes,  and yet be statistically confident that the decision made is not far (up to some arbitrary degree) to the one that would have been made if all members had voted.*

**What I currently have:**
I am interested in a numerical approach to solve this question. A related question enquiring about the analytical bayesian approach (posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020212/dynamic-voting-quorum)) suggests there is no tractable exact treatment. For the case in which $w_i=w$, however, the bayesian approach (proposed in another related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1916240/41533)) does have a tractable exact solution.